# How to get Errors(validation) in SpringFramework?

Tags: java, spring, validation

**I wrote a class to  implement the interface "Validator",and now how can I get the errors message without web environment?Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're talking about [resolving error codes to messages](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-conversion) from the reference guide.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan Stewart's reply gives a more practical solution, but the following approach might be useful as a fallback ... or for unit testing a validator class.

---

The validate method is called with an object that implements the [`Errors`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/Errors.html) interface
as a parameter.  On return, this object is populated with any errors that were detected by the validator.  You need to extract the information you need and render it.  How you do that depends on your requirements, and on how the errors object has been implemented.

If you use a errors object that has [`AbstractErrors`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/validation/AbstractErrors.html) as an ancestor class, the `toString()` method should render the error information as a message.  Try that first.